# Sharing a unix server among hacker colleagues

Tags: virtual-machine

We are buying a new beefy server for our department. I am interested in the best way to configure it so that each of us can have access to a virtual machine there. I think that's the right term in this context.

The goal is that we have root access and the ability to install and run software, changing cron jobs and so on. And to do is so that it is safe to do and won't break other colleagues who are doing the same with their software.

Assuming that the solution requires an "admin" to provision a VM for person X. Person X then gets an IP address that they can ssh and go to town on. Person X hopefully knows nothing about the VM and can pretend (almost) that they actually have a private server.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can install some virtualization on that server and each colleague can has his own VM. You can use Proxmox, Xen, VMWare or Docker for it. Each VM is independent server with independent OS. You have to have IP for each VM.

Comment: My goal is that my colleagues need to know nothing extra (about Vagrant or Docker or whatever) but can treat it *almost* as if ssh to that IP takes them to their own computer. Which of the options comes closer?

Comment: For your colleague it will be like you bought many servers instead of one. You will just give them IP address and root access to that VM. Only admin of that physical machine must know little more. I'm prefering proxmox because of web gui and clustering working out of the box.